# Does Cauchy-Schwarz hold for: $ \langle\textbf{u},\textbf{v}\rangle \;\leq ||\textbf{u}|| \cdot ||\textbf{v}|| $

Tags: inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I am wondering whether the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality does hold when absolute value is not considered for the LHS.

Let me explain: In standard Cauchy-Schwarz we have:

$| \langle \textbf{u},\textbf{v}\rangle |\;\leq \|\textbf{u}\| \cdot \|\textbf{v}\| $

But will this hold if no absolute value is taken for the left hand side?

My thoughts:

Since
$| \langle\textbf{u},\textbf{v}\rangle |\; = \|\textbf{u}\| \cdot \|\textbf{v}\| \cos(\alpha) $

we have that since $\cos(\alpha) \leq 1$, then the inequality:

$ \langle\textbf{u},\textbf{v}\rangle \;\leq \|\textbf{u}\| \cdot \|\textbf{v}\| $,  should hold.

May I get your opinion, thoughts? please!

Comment: Are you allowing complex values for $\left<u,v\right>$?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not really, I assume $u$ and $v$ are real. (by the way, what is the $\LaTeX$ sintax for inner product?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\langle u,v\rangle\leqslant\bigl\lvert\langle u,v\rangle\bigr\rvert\leqslant\lVert u\rVert.\lVert v\rVert$.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I agree, it makes sense.